# how to fetch mysql_query error

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to do this query using mySQL inside PHP and it's working with all tables except one "program", this is my code:

```
 $query = " INSERT INTO program (program_name )  
                    VALUES ($programName) "; 
            $result = mysql_query($query);
```

is there anyway to know why $result is always giving a false result?

This is the "program" table
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing quotes around your string value:

```
$query = " INSERT INTO program (program_name )  
                VALUES ('$programName') ";
```

To check for errors, just use `mysql_error()` (this is *not* a production ready example of how to do this):

```
$query = " INSERT INTO program (program_name )  
                VALUES ($programName) "; 
        $result = mysql_query($query); 
if (!$result) {
    echo mysql_error();
}
```

FYI, `mysql_*` functions are deparacated. You should switch to mysqli or PDO instead.

Comment: This is not a string, this is a variable

Comment: MySQL doesn't see the variable, they see the string created after the variable is interpolated. If you don't have your quotes in your query it isn't magically added for you by PHP or MySQL. Strings need to be enclosed by quotes.

Comment: Of course it is a variable in PHP but for MySQL it is a string value.  You should also consider using mysql_escape_string() to avoid problem with special characters like single quote.

Answer (score 2):

2 Things:

1. Your trying to insert more than 25 characters while your column has a length of 25 characters -> VARCHAR(25)
2. Your missing the quotes around the value:

   `$query = " INSERT INTO program (program_name )

                   VALUES ('$programName') ";`

Comment: Number 1 will just truncate it. It's not really an `error`

Answer (score -1):

Use or die( mysql_error() ) to check/debug the SQL error.

```
$query = " INSERT INTO program (program_name )  
                    VALUES ($programName) "; 
            $result = mysql_query($query) or die( mysql_error() );
```

Comment: That should be a comment i guess, this is no exact solution to his problem.

Comment: `$programName` needs quotes as it's a string. See John Condes answer